# Database import error syntax

Tags: sql, database, syntax, mariadb

I have tried to import my sql database into Phpmyadmin because I'm moving to another hosting.

I'm having a similar kind of error when trying to add another database. I don't know where the problem is. Could it be because my old or new server has some kind of software for MySQL what should be updated?

On the new server MariaDB 5.5.41 is running. Old one I haven't figured out yet.

What can I do next to find the error (and delete/replace it)?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '_transient_timeout_feed_mod_b9388c83948825c1edaef0d856b7b109', '1492459638', 'no' at line 2

Snippet from the specific code where the error should be:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES
(2857, '_transient_timeout_feed_mod_b9388c83948825c1edaef0d856b7b109', '1492459638', 'no'),
(2858, '_transient_feed_mod_b9388c83948825c1edaef0d856b7b109', '1492416438', 'no'),
(2859, '_transient_timeout_plugin_slugs', '1492502838', 'no'),
(2860, '_transient_plugin_slugs', 'a:1:{i:0;s:24:"wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php";}', 'no'),
```

Comment: try to remove the character between comman and single qoute. (2857, '). Maybe it is not a blank if you have copied the query from an text Editor.

Comment: I just tried, but still the same error appears..

Comment: Where do you write the query?

Comment: can you send me your database dropbox link ?

Comment: the comma at the end?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqyfwxfs3vh4ozw/thijmcn179_wordpress.sql?dl=0

Here is the database. Look for _transient_timeout_feed_mod_b9388c83948825c1edaef0d856b7b109 and you'lll find the right place

Comment: Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Etsa, it's not the comma. These are just 4 lines out of my code, it continues after the comma ... ;-)

Comment: it is working fine I have just created table form dropbox link and use this query

Comment: I can't import it in phpmyadmin... It uses MariaDB 5.5.41. Then I get the error I described above..

Comment: The precise syntax of the error implies that there are unbalanced single-quotes.  But I don't see it in the previous row, which is about 333KB long.  (Unless you removed such from the error message.)

Comment: @J.DD - what problem did you have when trying to import with phpmyadmin?  The .sql looks perfect compatible with all(?) versions of both MySQL and MyISAM, with the exception of `utf8mb4`, which does not exist before MySQL 5.5.3 and (I guess) before about the same version of MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES
(2857, '_transient_timeout_feed_mod_b9388c83948825c1edaef0d856b7b109', '1492459638', 'no'),
(2858, '_transient_feed_mod_b9388c83948825c1edaef0d856b7b109', '1492416438', 'no'),
(2859, '_transient_timeout_plugin_slugs', '1492502838', 'no'),
(2860, '_transient_plugin_slugs', 'a:1:{i:0;s:24:"wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php";}', 'no');
```

[image]
Try above code.

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any problem in your exported database file but When you are Exporting the database with phpMyAdmin, select "Custom - display all possible options".

Now you have plenty of options. You can change Database system on the *Format-specific options* and *Syntax to use when inserting data*.

and then import the database to the new server. You can change "SQL compatibility mode" in the phpMyAdmin import page.

Comment: I tried different kind of export options. And I tried changing the collation. None of it has worked so far. Everytime I get a different kind of error, unfortunately. I'm still busy trying and looking on Google for possible solutions. Haven't figured it out so far.

Comment: @J.DD Maybe it's a bug. I think you need to update your MariaDB. I've tested your exported file and there isn't any error or warning in it.